# Are For loops evil in R?

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, structure

I've heard that you're not meant to force a procedural programming style onto R. I'm finding this pretty hard. I've just solved a problem with a for loop. Is this wrong? Is there a better, more "R-style" solution?

The problem: I have two columns: Col1 and Col2. Col1 contains job titles that have been entered in a free form way. I want to use Col2 to collect these job titles into categories (so "Junior Technician", "Engineering technician" and "Mech. tech." are all listed as "Technician".

I've done it like this:

```
jobcategories<-list(
"Junior Technician|Engineering technician|Mech. tech." = "Technician",
"Manager|Senior Manager|Group manager|Pain in the ****" = "Manager",
"Admin|Administrator|Group secretary" = "Administrator")

for (currentjob in names(jobcategories)) {
  df$Col2[grep(currentjob,data$Col1)] <- jobcategories[[currentjob]]
}
```

This produces the right results, but I can't shake the feeling that (because of my procedural experience) I'm not using R properly. Could an R expert put me out of my misery?

EDIT

I was asked for the original data. Unfortunately, I can't supply it, because it's got confidential info in it. It's basically two columns. The first column holds just over 400 rows of different job titles (and the odd personal name). There are about 20 different categories that these 400 titles can be split into. The second column starts off as NA, then gets populated after running the for loop.

Comment: Most people would say for loops are to be avoided in R, mostly because other ways are quicker and more 'R-style'. However if it solves your problem and it doesn't slow things down to much, i often use them too. But i've learned programming in the old-school as well...

Comment: If this `for` loop is giving you the correct result and you are satisfied with how fast it is running, then there is absolutely nothing wrong with it. Don't worry too much about "avoiding for loops" until you write one that is much too slow. When it happens, trust me, you'll notice the bad performance. Typically, it is not "for loops" that are the problem, but naive code inside the loop that forces R to do a lot of copying of objects. So avoid "growing" objects in for loops.

Comment: Can you provide `data` too? I think in your case the `for` loop shouldn't be there at all, not because of speed, rather because its just not needed.

Comment: @DavidArenburg `grep()` doesn't accept a vector of patterns and here we are trying to match three patterns. How about `df<-data.frame(Col1=c("Junior Technician","Group secretary","Admin","Accountant","Senior Manager"), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)` for sample input.

Comment: @MrFlick I know that, but `grep` is not the only possible solution probably. Either way, I don't have time to check this right now.

Comment: @DavidArenburg Sure, `grep` probably isn't necessary in this case since there are no "real" regular expressions here. You could change the problem in the way @EdG did. I see what you're saying now.

Comment: Not always `for` loop is slower. I just got a lot of help from great R experts here on SO on not using `for` loop in my application, and actually was surprised that other functions (`sapply`, `Reduce`, `Curry`, etc) were slower. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30241461/trying-to-avoid-for-loop-with-sapply-for-gsub

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`for` loops are not 'evil' in R but they are typically slow compared to vector based methods and frequently not the best available solution, *however* they are easy to implement and easy to understand and you should not under-estimate the value of either of these.

In my view, therefore, you should use a `for` loop if you need to get something done quickly and can't see a better way to do it *and* you don't need to worry too much about speed.

Comment: I disagree with you on the "slow" part. Usually it's not the loop that's slow, it's that people are doing memory efficeint operations in a loop (ie `append()`). for loops can be faster than `sapply()` "alternatives". But that said it would be "wrong" to use a for loop so add up items in a vector when `sum()` exists. Use vectorized operations when possible is a good general rule.

Comment: That's good advice. I'll use the for loop in that example, and keep my eyes open for vector-methods where I can apply them. Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

You are right that for loops are often discouraged in R, and in my experience this is for two main reasons:

### Growing objects

As eloquently described in circle 2 of the [R inferno](http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf), it can be extremely inefficient to grow an object one element at a time, as is often the temptation in for loops. For instance, this is a pretty common yet inefficient work flow, because it reallocates `output` each iteration of the loop:

```
output <- c()
for (idx in indices) {
  scalar <- compute.new.scalar(idx)
  output <- c(output, scalar)
}
```

This inefficiency can be removed by pre-allocating `output` to the proper size and using a for loop or by using a function like `sapply`.

### Missing out on faster vectorized alternatives

The second source of inefficiency comes from performing a for loop over a fast operation when a vectorized alternative exists. For instance, consider the following code:

```
s <- 0
for (elt in x) {
  s <- s + elt
}
```

This is a for loop over a very fast operation (adding two numbers), and the overhead of the loop will be significant compared to the vectorized `sum` function, which adds up all the elements in the vector. The `sum` function is quick because it's implemented in C, so it will be more efficient to do `s <- sum(x)` than to use the for loop (not to mention less typing). Sometime it takes more creativity to figure out how to replace a for loop with a fast interior with a vectorized alternative (`cumsum` and `diff` come up a lot), but it can lead to significant efficiency improvements. In cases where you have a fast loop interior but can't figure out how to use vectorized functions to achieve the same thing, I've found that reimplementing the loop with the Rcpp package can yield a faster alternative.

### In summary...

For loops can be slow if you are incorrectly growing objects or you have a very fast interior of the loop and the entire thing can be replaced with a vectorized operation. Otherwise you're probably not losing too much efficiency, as the apply family of functions are performing for loops on the inside, too.

Comment: Thanks for the overview. It's basically a balance!

Answer (score 2):

You'll usually find there there is a non 'for-loop' way to do things.

For example:

If you create a simple table mapping your old jobs to the new ones:

```
job_map <- data.frame(
  current = c("Junior Technician", "Engineering technician", "Mech. tech.",
              "Manager", "Senior Manager", "Group manager", "Pain in the ****",
              "Admin", "Administrator", "Group secretary"),
  new = c(rep("Technician",3), rep("Manager",4), rep("Administrator",3))
)
```

And you had a table of jobs to reclassify:

```
my_df <- data.frame(job_name = sample(job_map$current, 50, replace = TRUE))
```

The match command will help you:

```
my_df$new <- job_map$new[match(my_df$job_name, job_map$current)]    
my_df
```

Comment: So this is the kind of thing I was interested in: a completely new way of doing it that I don't understand. Thanks! I'll try it out and see if I can make it work. If you were faced with the same problem, is this the way you would solve it?

Comment: I would probably take this approach, or `merge(my_df, job_map, by.x = "job_name", by.y = "current")`