# Trying to avoid for loop with sapply (for gsub)

Tags: r, for-loop, gsub, sapply

Trying to avoid using a `for` loop in the following code by utilizing `sapply`, if at all possible. The solution with loop works perfectly fine for me, I'm just trying to learn more R and explore as many methods as possible.

Objective: have a vector `i` and two vectors `sf` (search for) and `rp` (replace). For each `i` need to loop over `sf` and replace with `rp` where match.

```
i  = c("1 6 5 4","7 4 3 1")
sf = c("1","2","3")
rp = c("one","two","three")

funn <- function(i) {
  for (j in seq_along(sf)) i = gsub(sf[j],rp[j],i,fixed=T)
  return(i)
}
print(funn(i))
```

Result (correct):

```
[1] "one 6 5 4"     "7 4 three one"
```

I'd like to do the very same, but with `sapply`

```
#Trying to avoid a for loop in a fun
#funn1 <- function(i) {
#  i = gsub(sf,rp,i,fixed=T)
#  return(i)
#}
#print(sapply(i,funn1))
```

Apparently, the above commented code will not work as I can only get the first element of the `sf`. This is my first time using `sapply`, so I'm not exactly sure how to convert an "inner" implicit loop into a vectorized solution. Any help (even a statement - this is not possible) is appreciated!

(I'm aware of `mgsub` but this is not the solution here. Would like to keep `gsub`)

EDIT: full code with packages and belowoffered solutions and timing:

```
#timing
library(microbenchmark)
library(functional)

i  = rep(c("1 6 5 4","7 4 3 1"),10000)
sf = rep(c("1","2","3"),100)
rp = rep(c("one","two","three"),100)

#Loop
funn <- function(i) {
  for (j in seq_along(sf)) i = gsub(sf[j],rp[j],i,fixed=T)
  return(i)
}
t1 = proc.time()
k = funn(i)
t2 = proc.time()

#print(k)

print(microbenchmark(funn(i),times=10))

#mapply
t3 = proc.time()
mapply(function(u,v) i<<-gsub(u,v,i), sf, rp)
t4 = proc.time()

#print(i)

print(microbenchmark(mapply(function(u,v) i<<-gsub(u,v,i), sf, rp),times=10))

#Curry
t5 = proc.time()
Reduce(Compose, Map(function(u,v) Curry(gsub, pattern=u, replacement=v), sf, rp))(i)
t6 = proc.time()

print(microbenchmark(Reduce(Compose, Map(function(u,v) Curry(gsub, pattern=u, replacement=v), sf, rp))(i), times=10))

#4th option
n <- length(sf)
sf <- setNames(sf,1:n)
rp <- setNames(rp,1:n)

t7 = proc.time()
Reduce(function(x,j) gsub(sf[j],rp[j],x,fixed=TRUE),c(list(i),as.list(1:n)))
t8 = proc.time()

print(microbenchmark(Reduce(function(x,j) gsub(sf[j],rp[j],x,fixed=TRUE),c(list(i),as.list(1:n))),times=10))

#Usual proc.time
print(t2-t1)
print(t4-t3)
print(t6-t5)
print(t8-t7)
```

Times:

```
Unit: milliseconds
    expr min  lq mean median  uq max neval
 funn(i) 143 143  149    145 147 165    10
Unit: seconds
                                               expr min  lq mean median  uq max neval
 mapply(function(u, v) i <<- gsub(u, v, i), sf, rp) 4.1 4.2  4.4    4.3 4.4 4.9    10
Unit: seconds
                                                                                           expr min  lq mean median  uq max neval
 Reduce(Compose, Map(function(u, v) Curry(gsub, pattern = u, replacement = v),      sf, rp))(i) 1.6 1.6  1.7    1.7 1.7 1.7    10
Unit: milliseconds
                                                                                      expr min  lq mean median  uq max neval
 Reduce(function(x, j) gsub(sf[j], rp[j], x, fixed = TRUE), c(list(i),      as.list(1:n))) 141 144  147    145 146 162    10
   user  system elapsed 
   0.15    0.00    0.15 
   user  system elapsed 
   4.49    0.03    4.52 
   user  system elapsed 
   1.68    0.02    1.68 
   user  system elapsed 
   0.19    0.00    0.18
```

So, indeed in this case the `for` loop offers best timing and is (in my opinion) most straightforward, simple, and possibly elegant. Sticking to loop.

Thanks to all. All suggestions accepted and upvoted.

Comment: Usually, you use `microbenchmark` on all the things you're testing at the same time. Also, you might want to tag with `performance` on future questions if that's a concern again. By the way, Shenglin's answer actually does use `sapply`.

Comment: My goal was to also estimate how long each solution runs separately, in case an alternative solution is a lot faster than the loop. Upvoted Shenglin's answer too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach - advantage is conciseness but clearly not functional programming oriented - since it has border effect in modifying `i`:

```
mapply(function(u,v) i<<-gsub(u,v,i), sf, rp)
#> i
#[1] "one 6 5 4"     "7 4 three one"
```

Or here is a pure functional programming approach:

```
library(functional)
Reduce(Compose, Map(function(u,v) Curry(gsub, pattern=u, replacement=v), sf, rp))(i)
#[1] "one 6 5 4"     "7 4 three one"
```

What is does is that `Map(function(u,v) Curry(gsub, pattern=u, replacement=v), sf, rp)` builds a list of function which will respectively replace `1` with `one`, `2` with `two`, etc. Then these functions are composed and applied to `i`, giving the desired result.

Comment: no I just show `i` then and not the result of `mapply` !

Comment: Ok, I missed that part as it is commented

Comment: np, I added some 'sane' solution.

Answer (score 2):

This is sequential, so a loop seems natural. Here's a solution that is almost as bad as `<<-`:

```
n  <- length(sf)
Reduce(function(x,j) gsub(sf[j],rp[j],x,fixed=TRUE),c(list(i),as.list(1:n)))
# [1] "one 6 5 4"     "7 4 three one"
```

Really, you should use a loop.

Comment: Hmm .. cannot accept > 1 answer. Upvoted though. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
sapply(seq_along(sf),function(x)i<-gsub(sf[x],rp[x],i))
```

Comment: Could you add the output you see? It doesn't look much like the OP's to me. Try adding `[,1]` on the end.