# Generating Binomial variates without using inbuilt function in R

Tags: r

I am learning R and have just started simulating different probability distributions. I was trying to generate a [random variate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_variate) from the [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution). I am not willing to use the inbuilt function `rbinom` in R for doing the same. Among other methods, I decided to use the result that

> **the sum of `m` `Bernoulli(p)` random variables follow the `Binomial(m,p)` distribution.**

So, I wrote down a function for generating a Bernoulli random variate like this:

```
ber<-function(p)
{
    y<-runif(1)
    x<-ifelse(y<=p,1,0)
    return(x)
}
```

Now I'll use this Bernoulli variate to generate a binomial variate. Let the number of trials and the success probability be denoted by `m` and `p` as follows:

```
m<-10
p<-0.7
```

Now, I can just go on repeating the process of generating a Bernoulli variate for `m` times and then count (or here, sum) the number of successes. I also want to avoid any kinds of loops in this program as [`for` loops are often discouraged in R](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30240573/8484779). So, I took the help of `apply` and did something like this:

```
X<-apply(as.array(rep(p,times=m)),1,FUN=ber)
Y<-sum(X)
```

The variable `Y` is thus a binomial random variable.

**A demo output:**

```
> Y
[1] 9
```

### My problem and where I am stuck:

Suppose, instead of generating only one binomial variate, I want to generate `n` (say `10`) variates. I can use a `for` loop for that, but I want to **avoid** a `for` loop as I mentioned before. I am stuck as to thinking about how I can achieve that using some vector-based alternatives. I did use a `for` loop so finally, my code looked like this:

```
n<-10
for(i in 1:n)
{
    X<-apply(as.array(rep(p,times=m)),1,FUN=ber)
    print(sum(X))
    rm(X)
}
```

But, I'd very much like to know how to implement this part of the code without using any kind of loops in R. Any hints or suggestions regarding this is very much welcome. Any vector-based methods are also more than welcome here.

**A sample output:**

```
[1] 6
[1] 8
[1] 8
[1] 6
[1] 5
[1] 7
[1] 8
[1] 6
[1] 8
[1] 9
```

**Note:** Regarding the `rm(X)` in the last line of the `for` loop, I added that function so as not to get confused lest I need that `X` somewhere else later in that session.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need `replicate` like below

```
> replicate(n, sum(apply(as.array(rep(p, times = m)), 1, FUN = ber)))
 [1] 8 8 8 8 7 8 6 9 5 7
```

---

If you don't want to use the built-in `rbinom`, below is a shorter version of your code (following the same idea of yours)

```
replicate(n, sum(runif(m) < p))
```

Comment: Wow, nice one. I didn't know about the `replicate` function before. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

An option that uses a single call to `runif`:

```
colSums(matrix(runif(m*n), ncol = n) < p)
```