# Generating Geometric variates without using inbuilt function in R

Tags: r

I am learning R and have just started simulating from different probability distributions. I was trying to generate a random variate from the **Geometric Distribution**. I am not willing to use the inbuilt function `rgeom` in R for doing the same. Among other methods, I decided to use the result that:

> The **Geometric distribution** is the probability distribution of **the number of Bernoulli trials needed to get one success**.

I wrote the function for generating one Bernoulli variable as [in my previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67434285/8484779) named as `ber`, with `p` being the success probability.

Now to generate a Geometric variable, I can run a loop (I used a `repeat` loop here) and continuously generate a Bernoulli variable, check if it is a success or not and so on...

I did it like the following:

```
geom<-function(p)
{
    x<-1
    repeat
    {
        if(ber(p)==1) break
        x<-x+1
    }
    return(x)
}
```

One output as generated by `R` is:

```
geom(0.035)
[1] 9
```

### What I want to do and where am I stuck:

I want to use a vectorized approach instead of this `repeat` loop method to generate a Geometric variable but I seem to have run out of ideas as to how that can be achieved. Any helps/suggestions and hints are very much welcome in here.

**Note 1:** As to why I defined a new function `geom(p)`, I originally planned to generate not one, but many (say `n`) Geometric variates. I figured that defining a function as like this, and then using the `replicate` function to generate more similar variables with the same success probability is easier.

**Note 2:** I really apologize if some of my previous posts seem similar (in the sense that asking for suggestion for replacing a loop with some vector methods), but I am a newbie in `R` and I am still learning about vectorized methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without using a loop, you could use the fact that geometric random variables have an invertible cumulative distribution function and use [inverse transform sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling). The CDF of your version of the geometric variable (number of first success rather than the version where you count the number of failures before the first success) is:

```
F(x) = 1 - (1-p)^x,  x = 1, 2, 3, ....
```

We can solve for x in this:

```
x = log(1-F(x))/(log(1-p))
```

To use the with inverse sampling we need to take the ceiling of this to make it discrete:

```
geom <- function(n,p) {
  ceiling(log(runif(n))/log(1-p))
}
```

The above code exploits the fact that if `U` is uniform in `[0,1]` then so is `1-U`.

For example:

```
> set.seed(42)
> geom(10,1/6)
 [1]  1  1  7  2  3  4  2 11  3  2
> mean(geom(100000,1/6))
[1] 6.00359
```

**On Edit** An approach which is more along the lines of what you currently have is to create an entire vector of random variables, initialized all to `0`, and keep a list of indices of variables still "active" in the sense of experiments still waiting for a success. At each step, add 1 to these active variables, and with probability `1-p` keep some indices active into the next step:

```
geom2 <- function(n,p) {
  nums <- numeric(n)
  active <- 1:n
  k <- n
  while(k > 0){
    nums[active] <- nums[active]+1
    active <- active[runif(k) <= 1-p]
    k = length(active)
  }
  nums
}
```

This is still reasonably fast, though once `n` gets into the millions it visibly lags in comparison with the first definition.

I don't see any way to avoid using either a loop or an inverse transform.

Comment: Nice one... But is there a way to transform my method into a vectorised method? I would really like to know that

Comment: @DebarthaPaul I added a second approach which seems closer to what you were doing.