# How to create and add multiple sequences?

Tags: r

I want to create a sequence from 1 - 1000, in which I use the first 12 numbers, skip the next 12, and then take the next 12 again and so on (1:12,25:36,49:60 ...).

Does anyone know how to make this work?

Answer (score 2):

Very quickly (maybe stupid way), find the quotient of your series with an offset, use this as an index:

```
ix = (1:1000 - 1) %/% 12
```

You can see this groups your numbers by 12:

```
head(ix,25)
[1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2
```

To get alternate, take only ix which are divisible by 2:

```
 head((1:1000)[ix %% 2 == 0],50)
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 49
[26] 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 97 98
```

Answer (score 0):

Another method:

`a<-seq(1,1000,by=24)`: This stores the value of your starting points for each consecutive sequence.

Then you can use `sapply`:

```
sapply(a,function(x) seq(x,x+11))
```

This would generate:

```
    #Sample output:
    [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13]
 [1,]    1   25   49   73   97  121  145  169  193   217   241   265   289
 [2,]    2   26   50   74   98  122  146  170  194   218   242   266   290
 [3,]    3   27   51   75   99  123  147  171  195   219   243   267   291
 [4,]    4   28   52   76  100  124  148  172  196   220   244   268   292
 [5,]    5   29   53   77  101  125  149  173  197   221   245   269   293
 [6,]    6   30   54   78  102  126  150  174  198   222   246   270   294
 [7,]    7   31   55   79  103  127  151  175  199   223   247   271   295
 [8,]    8   32   56   80  104  128  152  176  200   224   248   272   296
 [9,]    9   33   57   81  105  129  153  177  201   225   249   273   297
[10,]   10   34   58   82  106  130  154  178  202   226   250   274   298
[11,]   11   35   59   83  107  131  155  179  203   227   251   275   299
[12,]   12   36   60   84  108  132  156  180  204   228   252   276   300
```

However,  if you want to use a `for-loop`:

```
b=NULL
for(i in 1:length(a))
{
    b=c(b,seq(a[i],a[i]+11))
}
```

Now you have `b` as:

```
 #Sample of b
 [1]   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  25  26  27  28  29  30
 [19]  31  32  33  34  35  36  49  50  51  52  53  54  55  56  57  58  59  60
 [37]  73  74  75  76  77  78  79  80  81  82  83  84  97  98  99 100 101 102
 [55] 103 104 105 106 107 108 121 122 123 124 125 126 127 128 129 130 131 132
 [73] 145 146 147 148 149 150 151 152 153 154 155 156 169 170 171 172 173 174
```

However, this method is not so efficient as [for loops are somewhat slow in R(compared to vectorised methods)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30240764/8484779).

Answer (score 0):

@StupidWolf has the simplest answer, but a function gives flexibility for any alternative sequences?

```
buildList <- function(seq = 12, skip = seq*2, max = 1000) {
  seed <- 1:seq
  out <- seed
  
  while(max(seed) < max){
    seed <- seed + skip
    out <- c(out, seed)
  }
  
  return(out[out <= max])
}
```

Specify the sequence of numbers, the number to skip and the maximum value.

buildList() will give your answer.

or
`buildList(seq = 4, max = 20)`
gives
`[1]  1  2  3  4  9 10 11 12 17 18 19 20`

Answer (score -1):

Try with an iterator of sorts, where the first call issues 1:12, the second call returns 25:36, etc. And then you call it 42 times (1000/12/2) to get to 1000:

```
wrap <- function(){
  i = 0
  myseq <- function(){
    out = 1:12 + i*12
    i <<- i+2
    return(out)
  }
  return(myseq)
}
myseq = wrap()

sapply(1:42, function(x) myseq())

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13] [,14] [,15]
 [1,]    1   25   49   73   97  121  145  169  193   217   241   265   289   313   337
 [2,]    2   26   50   74   98  122  146  170  194   218   242   266   290   314   338
 [3,]    3   27   51   75   99  123  147  171  195   219   243   267   291   315   339
 [4,]    4   28   52   76  100  124  148  172  196   220   244   268   292   316   340
 [5,]    5   29   53   77  101  125  149  173  197   221   245   269   293   317   341
 [6,]    6   30   54   78  102  126  150  174  198   222   246   270   294   318   342
 [7,]    7   31   55   79  103  127  151  175  199   223   247   271   295   319   343
 [8,]    8   32   56   80  104  128  152  176  200   224   248   272   296   320   344
 [9,]    9   33   57   81  105  129  153  177  201   225   249   273   297   321   345
[10,]   10   34   58   82  106  130  154  178  202   226   250   274   298   322   346
[11,]   11   35   59   83  107  131  155  179  203   227   251   275   299   323   347
[12,]   12   36   60   84  108  132  156  180  204   228   252   276   300   324   348
```