# Convert dplyr Chain to "for loop"

Tags: r, for-loop, dplyr, statistics, correlation

I am trying to calculate the correlation between price & cut in the diamonds data set, grouped by color.

I have constructed a pipeline of dplyr commands that returns what I want:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
data(diamonds)

df <- data.frame(group = diamonds$color, a = diamonds$price , b = diamonds$depth )

df %>% group_by(group) %>% summarize(Corr = cor(a,b)) %>% as.data.frame()
```

This outputs:(what I want)

```
  group         Corr
1     D  0.013415309
2     E  0.017037228
3     F  0.079294072
4     G -0.032000363
5     H  0.051953865
6     I  0.009288322
7     J  0.086863041
```

But I would like to create a for loop that serves the exact same purpose.

I understand the basics of a for loop, but to me it seems difficult to figure out the logic around such a task. Dplyr makes a lot of sense as it is.

Any ideas? Thank you (and happy holidays!)

Comment: If you had a data frame which contained just one color of diamond, how would you calculate the correlation of price and depth?

Comment: Ok, i'll give it some practice shortly

Comment: It might be helpful to know that your code above could be simplified to `diamonds %>% group_by(color) %>% summarize(Corr = cor(price,depth))`.

Comment: for(i in length(diamonds1$color)){
  
  Corr.i[i] <- cor(diamonds$price, diamonds$depth)
  
  output <- Corr.i[i]
}

output

Comment: This finds me the correlation for one, but categorizing by group in a for loop implies I think, a  new data frame or more detailed construction of the output df, and thats where I  lose a step

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the first thing to say is there's no particular reason to do this in a `for` loop - [often](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30240573/are-for-loops-evil-in-r) avoiding loops is preferable in R, and here the `dplyr` syntax is designed for this kind of operation.

However if you want to use a loop to get more familiar with them, I would be inclined to [`split()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/split) the data frame into a list of data frames, each of which contains one `color`.

```r
# Produces a list of length 7
diamonds_color_list  <- split(diamonds, ~color)

diamonds_color_list[[1]]
# # A tibble: 6,775 x 10
#    carat cut       color clarity depth table price     x     y     z
#    <dbl> <ord>     <ord> <ord>   <dbl> <dbl> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#  1  0.23 Very Good D     VS2      60.5    61   357  3.96  3.97  2.4 
#  2  0.23 Very Good D     VS1      61.9    58   402  3.92  3.96  2.44
#  3  0.26 Very Good D     VS2      60.8    59   403  4.13  4.16  2.52
#  4  0.26 Good      D     VS2      65.2    56   403  3.99  4.02  2.61
#  5  0.26 Good      D     VS1      58.4    63   403  4.19  4.24  2.46
#  6  0.22 Premium   D     VS2      59.3    62   404  3.91  3.88  2.31
#  7  0.3  Premium   D     SI1      62.6    59   552  4.23  4.27  2.66
#  8  0.3  Ideal     D     SI1      62.5    57   552  4.29  4.32  2.69
#  9  0.3  Ideal     D     SI1      62.1    56   552  4.3   4.33  2.68
# 10  0.24 Very Good D     VVS1     61.5    60   553  3.97  4     2.45
# # ... with 6,765 more rows
```

To calculate the correlation of `price` and `depth` for the first `color` you could do, `cor(diamonds_color_list[[1]]$price, diamonds_color_list[[1]]$depth)`.

It might seem tempting iterate through this list by index, starting with `for(i in 1:7) cor(diamonds_color_list[[i]]$price, diamonds_color_list[[i]]$depth)`. This is OK - though `for(i in seq_along(diamonds_color_list))` would be better.

However, I think code is more readable if you iterate over the color names, so I would do something along the lines of:

```
colors  <- names(diamonds_color_list) # D" "E" "F" "G" "H" "I" "J"

# Create empty list of correct length so you don't
# commit the sin of growing an object in a loop
results_list  <- vector(mode="list", length = length(diamonds_color_list))  |>
    setNames(colors)

# Loop through each color in the data frame 
# calculate the cor and add to the list
for (color in colors) {
    result <- list(
        color = color,
        cor = cor(
            diamonds_color_list[[color]]$price,
            diamonds_color_list[[color]]$depth
        )
    )
    results_list[[color]]  <- result
}

# Bind them together into a data frame
do.call(rbind, results_list)
#   color cor
# D "D"   -0.01352522
# E "E"   -0.005518622
# F "F"   0.006164055
# G "G"   -0.007661284
# H "H"   -0.02033827
# I "I"   -0.08299649
# J "J"   -0.04973188
```

All these functions are base R and do not require `dplyr`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answerp and explanation!! Our professor was keen on us making a for loop, even though data.table, dplyr, and even base R(with lapply) can do it faster and cleaner. Still I was missing this indexing of the color from my logic around for loops. (i.e. diamonds_color_list[[color]]$price). I was using the same df for defining the color and correlation variables, and try to iterate through each of the rows by indexing them. But as you suggest, it is better and clearer to avoid that.

Answer (score 0):

After spending quite some time with this & with the **invaluable** help of **Sam** in the answer, i was able to further simplify his answer, though his technique might be better when sharing results or for computing power efficiency (I am no loop expert by any means)

**STEP 1**: Create List of 7 elements - each has all prices & depths for  each of the 7 colors

```
diamonds_color_list  <- split(diamonds, ~color)     
diamonds_color_list[1]
```

**STEP 2**(Optional): Create a vector of colors (used to name the dataframe)

```
COLORS <- names(diamonds_color_list)
```

**STEP 3** # Create output df, with 7 rows (for each color),
and 2 columns (color & correlation)

```
output <- data.frame(Color = COLORS, Correlation = c(rep("")))

output
# Color Correlation
# 1     D            
# 2     E            
# 3     F            
# 4     G            
# 5     H            
# 6     I            
# 7     J
```

**STEP 4**: The loop

```
for (i in seq_along(COLORS)){ 
  
  Correlation <- cor(diamonds_color_list[[i]]$price,
 diamonds_color_list[[i]]$depth) 
  
  output[i, 2] <- round(Correlation, digits = 10)
  
}

output
# Color   Correlation
# 1     D -0.0135252221
# 2     E -0.0055186215
# 3     F  0.0061640548
# 4     G -0.0076612835
# 5     H -0.0203382723
# 6     I -0.0829964946
# 7     J -0.0497318835
```